# Elasticsearch Aggregation Query with multiple excludes

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a bunch of company data in an ES database. I am looking to pull counts of how many documents each company occurs in, but I'm having some problems with the `aggregation` query. I am looking to exclude terms such as "Corporation" or "Inc." Thus far I have been able to do this successfully for one term at a time as per the code below.

```json
{
    "aggs" : {
        "companies" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "Companies.name",
                "exclude" : "corporation"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns

```json
"aggregations": {
    "assignee": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "inc",
               "doc_count": 375
            },
            {
               "key": "company",
               "doc_count": 252
            }
         ]
     }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like

```json
{
    "aggs" : {
        "companies" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "Companies.name",
                "exclude" : ["corporation", "inc.", "inc", "co", "company", "the", "industries", "incorporated", "international"],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I haven't been able to find a way that doesn't throw an error

I have looked at the "Terms" section of Aggregation in the ES documentation and can only find an example for a single exclude.I'm wondering if it's possible to exclude multiple terms and if so what is the correct syntax for doing so.

Note: I know I could set the field to "not_analyzed" and get groupings for full company names rather than the split names. However, I'm hesitant to do this as analyzing allows a bucket to be more tolerant of name variations (ie Microsoft Corp & Microsoft Corporation)

Comment: For info, this has been implemented as of ES 1.5. See this issue for more info: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11959

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`exclude` parameter is a regular expression](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values), so you could use a regular expression that exhaustively lists all choices:

```
"exclude" :
    "corporation|inc\\.|inc|co|company|the|industries|incorporated|international"
```

Doing this generically, it's important to escape values (e.g., `.`). If it is not generically generated, then you could simplify some of these by grouping them (e.g., `inc\\.?` covers `inc\\.|inc`, or the more complicated: `co(mpany|rporation)?`). If this is going to run a lot, then it's probably worth testing how the added complexity effects performance.

There are also optional `flags` that can be applied, which are the options that exist in Java `Pattern`.  The one that might come in handy is [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE).

```
"exclude" : {
    "pattern" : "...expression as before...",
    "flags" : "CASE_INSENSITIVE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is old question, but newer answer: array currently supported for `exclude` exact match of list items

thus the array syntax in the OP is now valid and works as expected (in addition to valid regular expression answer too)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values